# Installing libfprint 0.99.0 using meson and ninja

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I'm trying to install libfprint 0.99.0 from here https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/releases The version available in Ubuntu repos do not support my fingerprint scanner (Elan). There is an instruction in here http://mesonbuild.com/Quick-guide.html how to use meson. Basically, I run all commands but at the end, after running ninja and building it I've no idea how to install it. Also running ninja-test gives me this:

$ ninja test
[0/1] Running all tests.
No tests defined.

So I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

Answer (score 3):

First, install all the dependencies with the following command

```
sudo apt-get install gtk+-3.0 libglib2.0-dev libnss3-dev libpixman-1-dev libusb-1.0.0-dev libx11-dev libxv-dev pkg-config ninja-build
```

Later, move to the container directory, usually in  `cd ~/libfprint`

Although the installation is recommended in a non-isolated environment, it is more complicated. So once in the mentioned directory follow the next commands:

`python3 -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate
 pip install -U pip
 pip install meson`

Once the isolated'environment was created is time to install the program. So the commands are as follow

```
venv/bin/meson builddir #After this line all dependencies should be in red YES
venv/bin/meson configure builddir -Ddoc=false -Dlibdir=lib
cd builddir
ninja
sudo ninja install
```

Finishing this, you must have the installation, to check out if it is working and if the installation is `Home` just go to the directory `~/libfprint/builddir/examples` and execute `sudo ./img_capture` to register a fingerprint, or `sudo ./verify` to verify a registered fingerprint.

If you want to use your fingerprint to login into your system, then you need to enroll it to **fprint-demo**. To do so just execute `sudo ./enroll` considering you are in the last mentioned directory.

In case you haven't install **fprint-demo** just do `sudo apt-get install fprint-demo` and to run it a simply `fprint_demo` is enough.

Cheers.

Comment: All was good until checking and enrolling. I have installed fprint-demo and running it got an error:

~/Downloads/libfprint-0.99.0/builddir/examples$ fprint_demo
** Message: 12:36:38.092: now monitoring fd 16

(fprint_demo:5639): libfprint-elan-WARNING **: 12:36:38.092: could not claim interface 0: LIBUSB_ERROR_BUSY

(fprint_demo:5639): libfprint-async-WARNING **: 12:36:38.092: device initialisation failed, driver=elan
** Message: 12:36:38.092: no longer monitoring fd 16